# Can NMB wire be used in conjuction with THW?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'd like to replace a section of 12 gauge solid THW wire that goes from the well's pressure switch to a point about 15 feet from where it goes into the ground. Is it okay to use 12/2 NMB wire (which I have on-hand) for that portion which is in a dry area, or do I need to stick with THW the whole way?

It is a 20A 220V circuit. The well pump is a half horsepower.

Comment: THW is a wire that would be in conduit, while NMB is a multi-wire cable (not an inherent problem, but it may change people's answers). Also, I don't believe THW is very common. Is THW what you meant to say? Also, how is the existing wiring run (conduit?) before going into the ground?

Comment: The wire was imprinted with "Trioseal Type TW VW-1 600V".  I got the impression that TW and THW were essentially the same thing.

The existing wire is not in conduit anywhere that I can see (yet), but I've come to expect non-adherence to electric code in this house so that's no surprise.  Part of my motivation for doing this at all is to get the no loose wires up off the ground, and two splices which are currently not in junction boxes replaced by on longer length and one junction box.

Comment: It's common to see "well wire" installed without a conduit. That's actually only acceptable to code inside the well casing (which is a rather large conduit) but it's a common sight anyway. Some states may relax the acceptable conduit types for well wiring outside the home (such as allowing poly water pipe used as conduit) but generally that is required to change to proper conduit before entering the building.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use THWN (sold as THHN) or XHHW individual wires to replace THW. All these are readily available at stores, and better stores sell it by-the-foot.

I cannot tell you that it's OK to use NM where THW is, because THW is allowed outdoors and NM is not allowed there.

Further, THW is used *inside conduit*, and NM is enormously larger than THW in terms of conduit fill.  Conduits large enough for 2 or 3 THW wires *may not be* large enough for an NM-B /3 cable. Any time you have an oval cable, you must compute conduit fill based on the wider dimension (because cables twist).

Additionally, any splices must occur inside a Junction Box.  You haven't said anything about whether there is a junction box at the point you wish to splice.

You cannot tear off the sheath of NM-B wire and use the individual wires as if they are THHN (unless the individual wires are marked like THHN wires, which they won't be).

The universal answer to "I have the wrong wires" is is "trade it on Craigslist/Facebook Marketplace for the right wires".

Comment: The idea was to use NM wire wit its sheath inside up to a junction box where it would be spliced to the THW wire. About 15 feet after that point it goes underground on its way to the outside of the home. 

The idea of trading wire never occurred to me.

Comment: Well if the NM cable fits based on the conduit fill rules, it is allowed in conduit indoors.